# Android M API 23 emulator Unfortunately, browser has stopped

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to launch browser on Android M Emulator. It keeps on crashing on every launch.

```
10-14 13:34:12.934: I/ActivityManager(1294): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 pkg=com.android.browser cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity bnds=[372,692][460,800] (has extras)} from uid 10007 on display 0
10-14 13:34:13.046: I/ActivityManager(1294): Start proc 5514:com.android.browser/u0a17 for activity com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity
10-14 13:34:13.131: W/System(5514): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/Browser/lib/x86
10-14 13:34:13.451: E/chromium(5514): [ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(698)] GLSurface::InitializeOneOff failed
10-14 13:34:13.591: D/WebViewTimersControl(5514): onBrowserActivityResume
10-14 13:34:13.591: D/WebViewTimersControl(5514): Resuming webview timers, view=com.android.browser.BrowserWebView{2900a61 VFEDHVC.. ......I. 0,0-0,0}
10-14 13:34:13.861: I/ActivityManager(1294): Displayed com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity: +833ms
10-14 13:34:14.377: A/DEBUG(962): pid: 5514, tid: 5559, name: GpuThread  >>> com.android.browser <<<
10-14 13:34:14.500: I/WindowState(1294): WIN DEATH: Window{bd73c76 u0 com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity}
10-14 13:34:14.556: I/ActivityManager(1294): Process com.android.browser (pid 5514) has died
10-14 13:34:14.560: W/ActivityManager(1294): Force removing ActivityRecord{1b3e625 u0 com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity t25}: app died, no saved state
```

Comment: I tried solutions like keeping SD card with 2 GB and keeping Host GPU checked but no use,

Answer (score 5):

Settings -> Apps -> Browser. then goto permission and enable storage permission to be enabled.because the storage permission is closed default.Just open it!

Answer (score 4):

Edit the Android Virtual Device settings inside you AVD manager that you are using and try starting your emulator with the "Use Host GPU" option enabled, this will help to fix your error with the browser.

For downloading files with the browser make sure you also add enough size to your SD Card option. After editing both settings, start Android and goto: Settings -> Apps -> Browser.
(If needed force to stop the browser) then goto permission and enable storage permission to be enabled. This will fix your error with the browser when downloading files.